# Why learning rate does not change?

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api

I use Tensorflow Object Detection API tutorial https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html to train my custom model. Follow this instructions, I have used config file from oficial GitHub repo and script train.py for training. I have seen in config file, that learning rate should be adaptive. It can be seen in this lines:

```
train_config: {
  batch_size: 24
  optimizer {
    rms_prop_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        exponential_decay_learning_rate {
          initial_learning_rate: 0.004
          decay_steps: 800720
          decay_factor: 0.95
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
      decay: 0.9
      epsilon: 1.0
    }
  }
```

Then, I used TensorBoard during the training and it showed me, that learning rate is constant for every training step. Why does it going? May it be, that TensorBoard see only initial value of learning rate and optimizer calculate real value of it on the fly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the API, the optimizer was built in this [file](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/builders/optimizer_builder.py). And [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/b4b8c723d377caae2f4243cf8fc711eab71736a1/research/object_detection/builders/optimizer_builder.py#L40) is the line for the `rms_prop_optimizer`. To build the optimizer learning rate, the function called a function `_create_learning_rate` that eventually called the `learning_schedules` under `object_detection/utils`.  And here is how the learning rate is scheduled in your example.

```
def exponential_decay_with_burnin(global_step,
                                  learning_rate_base,
                                  learning_rate_decay_steps,
                                  learning_rate_decay_factor,
                                  burnin_learning_rate=0.0,
                                  burnin_steps=0,
                                  min_learning_rate=0.0,
                                  staircase=True):
  """Exponential decay schedule with burn-in period.
  In this schedule, learning rate is fixed at burnin_learning_rate
  for a fixed period, before transitioning to a regular exponential
  decay schedule.
  Args:
    global_step: int tensor representing global step.
    learning_rate_base: base learning rate.
    learning_rate_decay_steps: steps to take between decaying the learning rate.
      Note that this includes the number of burn-in steps.
    learning_rate_decay_factor: multiplicative factor by which to decay
      learning rate.
    burnin_learning_rate: initial learning rate during burn-in period.  If
      0.0 (which is the default), then the burn-in learning rate is simply
      set to learning_rate_base.
    burnin_steps: number of steps to use burnin learning rate.
    min_learning_rate: the minimum learning rate.
    staircase: whether use staircase decay.
  Returns:
    a (scalar) float tensor representing learning rate
  """
  if burnin_learning_rate == 0:
    burnin_learning_rate = learning_rate_base
  post_burnin_learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(
      learning_rate_base,
      global_step - burnin_steps,
      learning_rate_decay_steps,
      learning_rate_decay_factor,
      staircase=staircase)
  return tf.maximum(tf.where(
      tf.less(tf.cast(global_step, tf.int32), tf.constant(burnin_steps)),
      tf.constant(burnin_learning_rate),
      post_burnin_learning_rate), min_learning_rate, name='learning_rate')
```

And here is the learning rate decay plot. Even after 100 000  steps, the decay is actually very small.
[image]

Comment: It's true, but there we can see, that by default  ```burnin_steps=0```.  And if there wasn't params for burnin_steps in config file, so this feature shouldn't be used, isn't it?

Comment: I've noticed that too, so I am trying to understand if there is any other places that makes sense

Comment: it have proceeded 100 000 steps

Comment: Here is the learning rate value after 100 000 steps `print(0.004*0.95**(100000/800720)) `, `0.003974458310087458`, so very small decay actually

Comment: So TensorBoard just round this value? Okey, it seems correct, thank you. I will try to set a smaller decay_steps parameter value and we'll see, how it will affect. Thank you for detailed explanation

Comment: this reminds the `smoothing` behavior of tensorboard, you may change the `smoothing` effect to be 0.

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation I read that the formula to compute decayed rate is:

```
decayed_learning_rate = learning_rate *
                    decay_rate ^ (global_step / decay_steps)
```

In this global_step need to be given as per:

```
[...] requires a global_step value to compute the decayed learning rate.
You can just pass a TensorFlow variable that you increment at each training step.
```

SO maybe you just need to pass that global_step parameter to have the rate effectively decay?

Comment: global_step is dynamic param, that is passed by tf.train during training process. We can see it in the ```_create_learning_rate()``` function in https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/builders/optimizer_builder.py as @danyfang noticed in his comment